# Getting issue : Illegal mix of collations in MySQL

Tags: mysql, collation

I have written this query

```
select * 
from order mbo 
where  storeId in(select storeid 
                  from store bs 
                  INNER JOIN  distributioncenter bd
                    on bd.distributionCenterId = bs.distributionCenterId            
                  where (bd.orderCloseTime > curtime() and date(bo.orderDate)>=date(now())
                     and bs.storeId=1112211)  
                   or (date(bo.orderDate)>date(now())and bs.storeId=1112211));
```

And this query is working fine in my local but when in other colleague's system i am getting below issue.

```
Illegal mix of collations (utf8_general_ci,IMPLICIT) and (latin1_swedish_ci,NUMERIC) for operation '>';
```

What could be the issue?

Comment: @Strawberry all the connected tables are in UTF8 format

Answer (score 0):

In your mysql database,"SHOW VARIABLES LIKE 'character_set_%'",make sure all of them are "UTF8"

Comment: you want me run that command?

Comment: I mean all the connected table format are in urf8, i have verified it.

Comment: Also Character_set_client?

Comment: 'character_set_client', 'utf8' its is in my system
but the exception is in prod

Comment: Not only the table,but the mysql client of your colleague's system and database need to be 'UTF8'

Comment: CAST worked fine for me. `select * from mb_opsorder mbo where  storeId in(select storeid from mb_store mbs INNER JOIN  mb_distributioncenter mbd on mbd.distributionCenterId = mbs.distributionCenterId where (CAST(mbd.orderCloseTime As Time) > curtime() and date(mbo.orderDate)>=date(now()) and mbs.storeId=1709) or (date(mbo.orderDate)>date(now())and mbs.storeId=1709));`